# MVC4 Kendo Grid DateTime template editor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, grid, kendo-ui, datetimepicker

I have this model:

```
public class MainModel 
{
private Guid m_id;
        public Guid Id
        {
            get { return m_id; }
            set { m_id = value; }
        }

        private string m_name;
        public string Name
        {
            get { return m_name; }
            set { m_name = value; }
        }
private ObservableCollection<Foundation> m_foundations;
        public ObservableCollection<Foundation> Foundations
        {
            get 
            {
                if (m_foundations== null)
                    m_foundations= new ObservableCollection<Foundation>();
                return m_foundations;
            }
            set { m_foundations= value; }
        }
}

public class Foundation
{
private ObservableCollection<Worker> m_workers;
        public ObservableCollection<Worker> Workers
        {
            get 
            {
                if (m_workers == null)
                {
                    m_workers = new ObservableCollection<Worker>();
                }
                return m_workers; 
            }
            set { m_workers = value; }
        }
}

public class Worker
{
[HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
        public Guid Id
        {
            get { return m_id; }
            set { m_id = value; }
        }
[DataType(DataType.DateTime), DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime BirthDate
        { get; set; }

}
```

and I have a partialView that receives this MainModel:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Controller", FormMethod.Post, new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }))
    {
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
<div id="workers">
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.Foundations[0].Workers)
 .Name("grid")
                .Columns(columns =>
                {
                    columns.Command(command => { command.Edit().Text("Edit"); command.Destroy().Text("Delete"); }).Width(200);
                    columns.Bound(p => p.Name);
                    columns.Bound(p => p.BirthDate).Width(100).Format("{0: dd-MM-yyyy}").EditorTemplateName("BirthDate");
})
.Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine).CreateAt(GridInsertRowPosition.Bottom))
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                    .Ajax()
                    .PageSize(20)
                    .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.Id))
                    .Create(update => update.Action("EditingInline_Create", "Controller"))
                    .Update(update => update.Action("EditingInline_Update", "Controller"))
                    .Destroy(update => update.Action("EditingInline_Destroy", "Controller"))
                    ))
</div>
```

The BirthDate editor has something like this

```
@model DateTime
@(
    Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(m=>m).Name("birthDatePicker")
)
```

the model is just fine with all the properties and datetimes.
the problem is:
the model.Foundations[0].Workers[].BirthDate has a valid date but in template editor gives me the datetime with minvalue model.

when i edit the column the value that appears will be something like 01-01-0001 instead of 15-03-2006 for example.
OK I just change the date but when i click Update the the value of the DateTime is always DateTime.Now. In EditingInline_Update the parameter 'worker' changed the BrithDate to DateTime.Now...the value that I changed is nowhere.

I read somewhere that this could be a culture formating issue but i did exactly as they said: 
Created a DateModelBinder and registered it in global.asax, but when in debug, the value passed is DateTime.Now...it's already changed there.
The Web.config has 
I changed the thread current culture and UIculture, changed the kendo.culture, checked in debug and everything seems to be right.
I even put javascript validator in the editor:

```
$("#birthDatePicker").kendoValidator({
        rules: {
            date: function (input) {
                var d = kendo.parseDate(input.val(), "dd-MM-yyyy");
                return d instanceof Date;
            }
        }
    });
```

this returns true and here I can see the date I want to change, but when goes to the modelbinder it somehow changes to DateTime.now

I'm sorry for the long but this is driving me crazy, I don't know if this is a bug for have collections inside collections or if is there something else that I missed.
Thanx in advance

Comment: I just started using EditorTemplates for the Kendo Grid. I have found that adding [UIHint="DateField"] in your model for DateFields and then and adding an editor at "~/Shared/EditorTemplates/DateField" will yield the rendering of your control in the grid.

Comment: Thanx Irb, I tried that before and it didn't work but I did it again from the beginning and it worked now :). I was making a editor for each attribute but now I making one for each data type. The only thing  not working was trying to parse the date at the model binder because the attempted value string had the time in it, so I re-arranged the code to parse with time too although I don't need it. Thanx again for the suggestion

Comment: https://kendoeditortemplate.codeplex.com/

Comment: This is excatly the issue i am haivng...my date always comes as null due to culture issue ...as i am having en-GB culture and kendo grid datetime column always have default culture and ny posy back value is always 01/01/0001...dman

Answer (score 0):

I have an MVC kendo-ui grid in one of my projects and it works just fine with the date in edit mode. What I noticed as different from your code was that I didn't write any attributes on the DateTime property in the model. My model simply looked like this:

```
public class TransactionViewModel
{
    [Key]
    public int TransactionId { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime TransactionDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
}
```

In the grid I bound the column in the following way:

```
columns.Bound(p => p.TransactionDate).Title("Date").Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}").EditorTemplateName("TransactionDate");
```

And, even though my editor template looked a bit different than yours, the code you provided worked just fine when I tested to replace mine with yours.

```
@model DateTime?
@(Html.Kendo().DatePicker()
    .Name("TransactionDate")
    .Value(Model == null ? DateTime.Now.Date : ((DateTime)@Model).Date)
)
```

To handle culture issues I've added the following code as well:

```
@{
    var culture = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.ToString();
}
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/cultures/kendo.culture." + culture + ".min.js")"></script>
<script>
    kendo.culture("@culture");
</script>
```

I would suggest you try the following:

- Remove attributes in model to verify that they're not causing any problems. You can add them later on when it's all working.
- Try to specify a different date format, or no date format. If you specify one format and the user's browser wants to render it in another format you might get into trouble.